# Term for assistant of assistant manager

Tags: word-choice

Do you call an assistant of an assistant manager *vice-assistant manager*, *deputy assistant manager*, *assistant-assistant manager* or something else?

Comment: I have a hunch this will vary a great deal according to corporate structure.

Comment: is the assistant of an assistant manager a manager? I would think they are simply an assistant.

Comment: Flanders and Swann mentioned the Chief Assistant to the Assistant Chief (but not seriously.)

Comment: Obviously, Assistant (to the) Assistant Regional Manager.

Comment: I agree with @onomatomaniak and consequently I don't think there is a right answer.  You can call it what you like: assistant manager's assistant, sub-assistant manager, etc. or something more descriptive of their actual role.

Comment: This assistant for the Assistant Manager will help / assist the Assistant Manager when the Assistant Manager is too busy or is not around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the manager is the highest authority, and the assistant manager is his or her deputy, and if the assistant to the assistant manager supervises, why not call her a supervisor?

If she doesn't supervise, why not call her an assistant?